# CSS flip animation varies in browser

Tags: css

Here is a simple horizontal flip animation - http://jsfiddle.net/vntajmgh/2/
and I see 2 issues:

1. Open the url in chrome. Hover over the red div. The flip is ok, but the background color for the back div(blue) is not applied.
2. Open the url in firefox. The flip is like stuck. I can see the blue colored back div sometimes.

I guess it's 'stuck' here because the height is `100vh`, which when reduced works fine, but should it not work with the full height too?

```css
.flip-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 800px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;    
}
.flipper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform linear 0.6s;
}
.flipper div {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipper .front {
    background: red;
}
.flipper div:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/3px-tile.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}
.flipper .back {
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipper:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div id="1front" class="front">1-front</div>
        <div id="1back" class="back">1-back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gf3g8sz1/1/

Comment: I think the animation gets "stuck" because when the div becomes narrower, the mouse no longer hovers over the element (in Firefox). If I follow the animation with the mouse (from left to right) it works.

Answer (score 1):

Add an overflow hidden to the parent div(flip-container). When we are using 100vh(view port height) with rotate transform property, its actually taking more height than the view port has. so hide it by using overflow hidden.

**css**

```
.flip-container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

To get the same hover effect in both browser you have to modify the hover CSS.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p0sL3v73/1/)

Comment: Thank you Shibin. There is an issue in firefox. The flip occurs smooth and the blue color is visible for back div. But when you move away your pointer from the blue div, the color vanishes and then it flips back to red. This doesn't happen in chrome

Answer (score 0):

removing:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

will make the back color visible

Answer (score 0):

The problem in Chrome is caused by the pseudo element. I have changed the way to get the image blended with red without an pseduo element, and now it works OK.

The problem in FF is caused by the reduced-disappeared size of the element that receives the hover. I have changed the hover so that it is triggered by the container, and now it works also ok.

It is always a good idea to avoid using hover on transformed elements, they usually give some kind of problems

```css
.flip-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 800px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;    
}
.flipper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform linear 0.6s;
}
.flipper div {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipper .front {
    background: red;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,0,0,0.5),rgba(255,0,0,0.5)), url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/3px-tile.png");
}
.flipper .back {
    background: blue;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div id="1front" class="front">1-front</div>
        <div id="1back" class="back">1-back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```